# Вкладки для сайта

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите как на JS сделать что то типо tab control (вкладок).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например [так](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/f7bJF/) или [так](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/p3sfy/), или [так](http://jsfiddle.net/iamacatperson/R85tE/), или [даже с поддержкой истории](http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/xUS4D/)